# Ionic 3: How to get push notification data into the app using Firebase?

Tags: cordova, firebase, push, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (cordova-plugin-fcm) in my Ionic 3 app. So far I'm able to receive a push notification from Firebase both when the app is in background or in foreground.

In background though, I'm not getting the data into the app. So here's what happens:

- app is on sleep or not running at all
- I tap on my received OS Notification (tested on Android)
- the app comes to the foreground
- the app is starting perfectly
- **the listener with the push data is not getting called**

Here is my code for registering the listener:

```
constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    private fcm : FCM
) { this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => console.log(data)); }
```

As you see I'm subscribing directly in the constructor, but I also tried

```
platform.ready()
```

Which didn't work either. I also tried to send specific keys in my notification like `"data":{"foo" : "bar"}` or `"notification":{"foo" : "bar"}` or `"message":{"foo" : "bar"}`. This method should mark the actual payload of a notification to tell the preprossesing in the OS service to pass it to the app, but none of them helped.

It seems like the data will not be transfered into the app when the app is not active. All explanations online tell to subscribe to the listener like above and just check the `data.wasTapped` property. But since the listener is not getting called at all, I'm pretty powerless at this point. Maybe I should try "phonegap-plugin-push" instead?